# Are there UNICODE symbols for hex representation?

Tags: unicode, hex, character

I want to dump a data stream, and display say the character 0x12 as ONE CHARACTER '12' with maybe a tiny '1' in top left corner and '2' in bottom right. There is a similar concept with UNICODE Control Pictures https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_Pictures which displays 'DC2' as one character, with a tiny 'D' top left and '2' bottom right - but I would like it in hex.

**EDIT** I can easily display non-printable bytes as 2 characters e.g. byte 0x12 as 'x' + '1' + '2' but that takes 3 print positions. I want it to print as similar to '%' where the top left '0' is replaced by a small graphical '1' and the bottom right '0' replaced by a small graphical '1', and no graphical stroke. This is not some convert-to-printable-for-transmission-purposes like base64; this is to enable me to print non-display bytes and view their internal bit representation.

Maybe an example would help. Let's take a 32-bit value(4 bytes) of 0x00004050 (big-endian); I want to see 4 characters something like '%%@P'

**EDIT2** The UNICODE text generated will be written to a UNICODE log file, for viewing by eyeball in a text editor, browser, or similar. Using UNICODE Control Pictures I could do that now, but I want HEX and not the C0 Control Name abbreviation displayed for non-printable characters.

Sample of what I want to see (via UNICODE) for 4 hex, 4 symbols, 4 numbers and 4 alphabetic:
[image]

Comment: You seem to be asking for a base-256 encoding. I am not aware of any standard way to do so. You can somewhat arbitrarily locate 256 consecutive Unicode code-points and roll your own. If you want to be a little more standard then at the cost of a certain expansion in length, perhaps you could just use base-64? There are numerous libraries for encoding and decoding bytestreams in base-64.

Comment: I don't think so. We can hope for it in Unicode 10.0. Here is the opposite effect with paired, individual, full-width characters, digits separated by U+2060, pairs separated by U+00A0: ０⁠１ ２⁠３ ４⁠５ ６⁠７ ８⁠９ Ａ⁠Ｂ Ｃ⁠Ｄ Ｅ⁠Ｆ

Comment: How are you rendering the text?

Comment: So something like a Unicode hex-viewer which uses 1 character per byte rather than 2?

Comment: @JohnColeman yes. Years ago I was using a DataScope(?) to monitor RS232 communication lines, which displayed either characters or tiny-hex, one screen position for each byte, with presumably a custom ROM chip for generating the pixels to display.

Comment: You could always just use one of the "private use" areas of Unicode to define your own custom codepoints that represent bytes 0x00-0xFF, then create your own font to render those codepoints as desired.

Answer (score 4):

No.

There was a proposal for "[Hex Byte Pictures for Unicode](ftp://kermit.columbia.edu/kermit/ucsterminal/hex.txt)" proposed by the kermit developers. According to their [standards page](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/standards.html) that proposal was rejected.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I want, but it got rejected - HUH!?